# apply function to varying number of columns using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

|  | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 40 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 70 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 6 | 500 |

I have a table that looks like this i want to apply `regex = '^p\d'` to search for specific column names and create new columns name `n{1}, n{2}, ...`

- `n{1} = p{1}/ SQUARE ROOT OF (p{1}**2 + p{2}**2 + p{3}**2 + ...)`
- `n{2} = p{2}/ SQUARE ROOT OF (p{1}**2 + p{2}**2 + p{3}**2 + ...)`
- and so on upto... n_{n}
- index location of `p1, p2, p3` varies for different csv files. So I am trying search using regex to search column names.
- number of `p` rows also varies for different csv files. I am trying to stop creating new columns loop if the next `p` column does not exist. Not sure how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_1 = {'p1': [1, 2, 3],
          'p2': [4, 5, 6],
          'p3': [3, 70 ,6],
          'p4': [40, 8, 500],
         }



df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
df1
```

Comment: So your columns may contains column names other than `p[number]` right? and you just need to get the columns `p[number] and convert them to n[number]`, do you want the same in same dataframe or separate dataframe

Comment: 1. there are many columns and they contain column names other than `p[number]`. I dont want to touch them. I just want to use `p[number]` to create new columns `n[number]`.

2. same dataframe.

Comment: Hi @n3a5p7s9t1e3r I have written an answer using regex, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python string function to achive the same, but since you asked for regex solution, here is how you can do using the same.

```
r = re.compile("^p\d")
qualified_columns = list(filter(r.match, df1.columns))
new_col_names = [re.sub(r'p(\d+)', r'n\1', col) for col in qualified_columns]
df1[new_col_names] = df1[qualified_columns].div(df1.pow(2).sum(axis=1).pow(1./2), axis=0)
```

**Result :**

```
   p1  p2  p3   p4        n1        n2        n3        n4
0   1   4   3   40  0.024799  0.099197  0.074398  0.991973
1   2   5  70    8  0.028304  0.070760  0.990643  0.113216
2   3   6   6  500  0.005999  0.011998  0.011998  0.999838
```

Answer (score 1):

The index location of the columns does not matter if you are reading in the column names correctly.

```py
pcols = [col for col in df1.columns if col.startswith('p')]
pnums = [col.split('p')[-1] for col in pcols]
pcols_rss = df1[pcols].apply(lambda row: np.sqrt(np.sum(row**2)), axis=1)
for col, num in zip(pcols, pnums):
    df1.loc[:, f'n{{{num}}}'] = df1[col] / pcols_rss
```

**Output**

```
   p1  p2  p3   p4      n{1}      n{2}      n{3}      n{4}
0   1   4   3   40  0.024799  0.099197  0.074398  0.991973
1   2   5  70    8  0.028304  0.070760  0.990643  0.113216
2   3   6   6  500  0.005999  0.011998  0.011998  0.999838
```